# Looking for irreducible polynomials with "asymmetric roots"

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm looking for irreducible polynomials over $\Bbb {Q} $ with the following property: for some roots $\alpha$ the negative of the root is also a root, whilst for other roots this property does not hold.

Thanks

Comment: first guess: no such animal. no time. later.

Comment: Let $P\in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ such that $P(\alpha) = P(-\alpha) = 0$ for some $\alpha\neq 0$. Let $\tilde{P}(X) = P(-X)$ and consider $\gcd (P,\tilde{P})$.

Comment: This is a bit too terse for me - are you pointing out that the gcd over the rationals must be 1, or are you inviting us to look at their gcd over the complex numbers?

Comment: @Justpassingby The $\gcd$ in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

Comment: @Daniel OK, so what can we conclude from the fact that $P(X)$ and $P(-X)$ have no common divisors in $\mathbb Q[X]$?

Comment: @Justpassingby By the assumptions, it follows that $\gcd(P,\tilde{P}) \neq 1$. In $\mathbb{C}[X]$, we have $X^2 - \alpha^2 \mid \gcd(P,\tilde{P})$. So if $P$ is irreducible, it follows that $\gcd(P,\tilde{P}) = P$, hence $\tilde{P} = (-1)^{\deg P}\cdot P$. Since an odd polynomial is irreducible if and only if it is $X$, but that case was excluded by the assumption $\alpha\neq 0$, it follows that $P$ is even, hence $P(X) = R(X^2)$.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks, I feel like it is beginning to dawn. I can see that the gcd in $\mathbb C[X]$ must be nontrivial, but why exactly do the assumptions imply that the gcd in $\mathbb Q[X]$ is nontrivial?

Comment: @Justpassingby Because for any fields $K\subset L$, the gcd of two polynomials in $K[X]$ may either be computed in $K[X]$ or in $L[X]$. They are the same ! That is a good exercise.

Comment: @Roland I get it! The minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb Q$ divides both $P(X)$ and $P(-X)$ so they must have a nontrivial common factor in $\mathbb Q[X]$ and therefore, being irreducible themselves, be multiples of each other.

Comment: @Daniel please promote your "comment" to an answer...

Comment: @Justpassingby, for two $\Bbb Q$-polynomials, the gcd over $\Bbb Q$ and the gcd over $k$ are the same for any $k\supset\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $p(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial such that $p(x)$ and $p(-x)$ share a root. Then $p(x)$ must be a scalar multiple of $p(-x)$, by irreducibility. So if this property holds for some roots it must hold for all roots.